# Why does sbt update fail with "Conflicting cross-version suffixes" with Spark GraphX?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-graphx

Here is my sbt for spark with scala on Intellij

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.10" % "2.1.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

I get the following error

```
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in:org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast,           org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, org.scalatest:scalatest, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core,org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, org.scalatest:scalatest, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common
```

Can anyone let me know how to correct this. To me it looks like spark-graphx is contradicting with spark_core. How do I find the correct SBT file? or what should i do to get this sbt file working. I am ok with lowering the version of graphx as well as spark but would prefer to lower the version of spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you sbt file, the dependencies are called spark-_. You're using different scala version in your graphX dependency.

If you use Spark 2.x I recommend use scala 2.11 so you only have to change graphx dependency.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

Anyway, you don't need to write scala version in every dependency. Sbt will infer according scalaVersion value if you write two percentage sign %%. [Here](https://github.com/phatak-dev/spark2.0-examples/blob/master/build.sbt), you can see an example.

Comment: Hi that was neat.
But when i looked in  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.10/2.2.0 the maximum graphx I could find was for 2.10. Why was that so ?

Comment: Better take a look at maven central. It's the official repository. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgraphx

Comment: I used to google and take the first one for the sbt. I understand how wrong I was. Thnaks @gasparms